# How to put a Dojox.grid in a dijit.Dialog

Tags: dialog, grid, dojo

I've read through the posts about dojox.Grid here, including the one about the tabcontainer, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I have a grid that I am adding programmatically which works a treat if the grid is in the "main" markup, but ceases to display if I put the grid in a dialog.

Any ideas as to why? Using dojo 1.3.1.

```
dijit.byId("myDialog").show();
var gridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
      data : {
        identifier : "id",
        items      : [
                      {"id" : 1, "label" : "foo"},
                      {"id" : 2, "label" : "bar"},
                      {"id" : 3, "label" : "baz"}
        ]
      }
    });

    /* A simple layout that specifies column headers and
     * mappings to fields in the store */
    var gridLayout = [
            {name : "ID",    field : "id",    width : "50%"},
            {name : "Label", field : "label", width : "50%"}
    ];

    /* Programmatically construct a data grid */
    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                       store     : gridStore,
                       structure : gridLayout
               }, "gridNode");

    /* Tell the grid to lay itself out since
     * it was programmatically constructed */
    grid.startup();
```

The markup is:

```
 <div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="myDialog" title="Multiple Addresses" style="width:400px;height:300px" >
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="gridNode" style="positon:relative;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

Thanks for any help,
Ruprict

Answer (score 3):

So, the problem I  was having seeem to stem from not putting an explicit style on the grid container div (gridNode) Once I did this:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="gridNode" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
```

It started working.

Answer (score 1):

FYI. I am doing a similar thing (grid in a dialog) and have discovered if I try to modify the store (or at least call setStore on the grid) while the dialog is hidden, errors occur. Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating all of it programatically so that didnt work for me, i had to connect to _getFocusItems method of the dialog, thats happen only the animation of the dialog ended.

```
lov.connect(lov,"_getFocusItems",dojo.hitch(this,function(){
                var dijitTitle = new dijit.TitlePane({
                    title: "Resultados",
                    toggleable:false,
                    open:true,
                    style:"min-width:98%;display:inline-block;width:98%;height:"+dialogStyle.h-100+"px;",
                    baseClass:"dijitTitlePane qtResultsTitle"
                },div);
                dijitTitle.startup();

                var fisaSubGrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                    store:store,
                    structure: layoutRate,
                    autoHeight:"true",
                    autoWidth:true,
                    initialWidth:dialogStyle.w-50+"px",
                    plugins: {
                        pagination: {
                            description: false,
                            sizeSwitch: false,
                            pageStepper: true,
                            gotoButton: false,
                            maxPageStep: 5,
                            position: "bottom",
                            defaultPage: 2,
                            defaultPageSize: 10
                        }
                    }
                });
                dijitTitle.addChild(fisaSubGrid);
                fisaSubGrid.startup();

            }));
```